# Cascade delete dependent objects in a one to one relation

Tags: .net, entity-framework

After reading numerous articles and possible solutions on SO, I am lost with this problem.

I have 2 objects, let's call them `A` and `B`. `A` is principal, `B` is dependent. It is modeled as an one to one relationship with both ends being required.

Object has a lot relations to several objects.

The relationship has been setup by using the modelbuilder:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<A>()
            .HasRequired(a => a.B)
            .WithRequiredPrincipal(b => b.A)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Because `A` is the principal end and has a required relationship to B, I expect this relation to be cascading. However, it is not:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.A_dbo.B_AId". The conflict occurred in database "ABC", table "dbo.B", column 'AId'.

Do I have to remove all the dependent relations manually? I thought that was not the idea of a cascading delete. What should I do to make this work?

Comment: Did you mean to explicitly tell it not to? .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

Comment: I will disable cascading delete from the "opposite" (dependant object). If i do not specify this, A will be removed if I remove B. This will lead to circularity issues.